# Printing price tag according to purchase

Tags: ms-access, vba

All the best to you all.

I am gravely in need of a support. Please help if possible and forgive my weakness in English.

The problem is i need to print various products' price tag in various numbers using an invoice no. I mean according to the amount of purchased products. Suppose pucrchase no 18. 1st purchased product is Pen which is purchased at 50 pieces and 2nd one is Apple at 100 pieces. i need to print pages (report) with 50 (33, Pen, £0.25), 100 (34, Apple,£0.5) etc in it with a single click. Is it possible?

even links or videos will be enough if something like this is already solved.

BTW, I've posted it to another site aas well. Thanks a lot for your time and support.

Comment: I'm not completely sure I understand what you're trying to achieve but it sounds like you want to populate an invoice template using a list of purchased products.  To do that you need to learn about vlookup or index search in order to extract data from your list.  It would be useful if you could show an example of your data and also an example of how you would like it to appear.  A picture is better than 1000 words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set up a dummy table to hold the multiple records that you want. When you click your button, you loop through the purchase order lines and for each line set up a loop for the number of pieces ordered and in that loop add a row to your dummy table. (Unverified) code:

```
CurrentDB.Execute "DELETE FROM PriceTags"   'PriceTags is your dummy table
Set rsPurchaseLines = CurrentDB.OpenRecordset("select * from PurchaseLines where PurchaseNo = " & txtP_No)
With rsPurchaseLines
    Do While Not .EOF
        strInsertSQL = "insert into PriceTags (TagDescription) values (" & _
                       !ItemID & ", '" & Replace(!ItemName, "'", "''") & "', £" & !ItemPrice & ")"
        For intPieces = 1 To !Pieces
            CurrentDB.Execute strInsertSQL
        Next intPieces
        .MoveNext
    Loop
End With

Set rsPurchaseLines = Nothing
```

Then set up your report's record source to be the dummy PriceTags table.